# Firebase Messaging Notification campaign send count drop

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

For some reason the number of send notifications in my Firebase Messaging Campaign has dropped dramatically from 416 sends on 11 October to just 41 sends on 18 October.

[image: Notification Graph]

This has happened for no apparent reason. My personal Android / iOS devices have also stopped receiving the notifications. They were working just fine last week. And I'm sure that the FCM token is being refreshed regularly, as I open the app daily.

I could not find any useful information on internet.

Has anyone encountered this situation before? What was the reason and how did you solve it?